# Change order of columns spreahseet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, output

I just want to confirm if there is any inbuilt function is google apps script to reorder the columns in the spreadsheet or do I have to do something like this -

```
  var r = currentSheet.getRange(1, 1, currentSheet.getLastRow() - 1, currentSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  for(var i1=0, dLen=r[0].length; i1<dLen; i1++) {
    //something to reorder
  }
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

it depends. if you just want to present the data in a different order, just use the built-in "=query" cell function, selecting the rows in the order you want.
query has some limitations thou. for example each column must have a consistent type on all rows (date, number, string etc). there arr other built-in functions that do similar things.

if you actually want to change the source range, you need to do it by getting the entire range array values, transforming it (possibly needing to take care of functions too) and writting the entire new array in a single range write.

Comment: Thank you @Zig. I want to work using the script. So I may have to work using the array only

Comment: that code will end up being a loop on the columns where you build a new array based on the source array. at that point you could save some cpu/ram by first preallocating your new array (each row made of `new Array(cols)`) to prevent changing row size changes or reallocations.

Comment: Thank you for the hint @Zig. I did work on it the same way.